# How to get a total from with "Class" in python, then calling it into another file main()?

Tags: python, class

My assignment is : Assume you sell t-shirts ( or any other item), and all t-shirts cost the same, they all have the same price

Define a class called Sale. The first line of the constructor would only have 3 arguments: self, item and quantity. In addition, the constructor has   an attribute for the price and an attribute to hold the total for the sale.

The program assumes the same price for every item, so you can initialize the price in **init** using the price of your choice. Just like we did with the car example I showed in the lecture, where the speed attribute was initialized to zero in **init**, you could initialize  total at total to zero

The class should have 4 methods to:

A method to calculate the total
A method to return the total
A method to return the item
A method to return quantity
The program importing the file with this class needs to create an instance of the Sale class. Assuming,   the file with the class definition is sale.py and the class is Sale, it would look something like this

new_sale = sale.Sale('Men medium blue', 10)

When I run the program that creates the class instance, assuming the price in the class was set to 9.99, the output would look something like this

new_sale = sale.Sale('Men medium blue', 10)

The total for 10 t-shirts  Men medium blue is $ 99.9

'''class Sale:

```
def __init__(self,item,quantity):
    self.item=item
    self.quantity=quantity
    self.total=self.price*self.quantity
    self.price=10
def get_item(self):
    return self.item

def get_quantity(self):
    return self.quantity

def get_total(self):
    return self.total
```

'''
**This is my main function in another file, I'm trying to get the user input quantity to multiply by the set price ($10) in Class**

'''

import sale

def main():

```
itemQ=input("Please enter type of t-shirt: ")
quanT=int(input("Please insert number of t-shirt you wish to buy: "))

theSale= sale.Sale(itemQ, quanT)

print("The item is ", theSale.get_item(), " and a quantity of ", theSale.get_quantity(), "and total of ", theSale.get_total())
```

main()

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple minor changes should get it working:

```
# sale.py
def __init__(self, item, quantity):
    self.item=item
    self.quantity=quantity
    self.price=10
    self.total=self.price*self.quantity # you have to define price before you use it to calculate the total
```

```
# add these two lines at the end of you main .py file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

See python docs on main method: [**main**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)